# Can't bind to 'consoleMessages' since it isn't a known property of 'app-console'

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I am getting following error message when unit test angular app

> Can't bind to 'consoleMessages' since it isn't a known property of 'app-console'.
>
> 1. If 'app-console' is an Angular component and it has 'consoleMessages' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'app-console' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
> 3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("

```
  <br>
     <app-console [ERROR ->][consoleMessages]="consoleMessages"></app-console>
      </div>"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/EntitlementCreateComponent.html@135:15
      'app-console' is not a known element:



TestBed.configureTestingModule({
   imports:[HttpClientTestingModule,RouterTestingModule,FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule],
   declarations: [EntitlementCreateComponent,NGXSpinner],
   //schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA] //Note schemas is commenented
      })
```

Comment: schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA] adding this error disappears but I want to know why this error appears

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are getting the error is because you are referencing the `consoleMessages` property of your `app-console` custom element. And the angular compiler can't find that property.

The [`CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA`](https://angular.io/api/core/CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA) defines a schema that contains custom elements that are non-angular. So, by adding that schema, you are telling angular to ignore type checking on that element. It's probably not what you want.

My guess is that one of several things are going on:

1. `consoleMessages` property is not defined as a public property on the `AppConsole` class.
2. You have not configured `AppConsole` correctly in your test harness. Are you module in your test harness?

Comment: Since I am new to this I didn't configure AppConsole